# when running shell script with sudo, user path is not available

Tags: linux, bash, sh

I'm writing a shell script to start a few processes for me. Because those processes need sudo access, I run my shell script with sudo. However, I don't have access to my path variables when I do that. I've added a shell script to /etc/profile.d/extra-path.sh that adds those for my user.

Could someone tell me the way I should add those path variables so they can be accessed in the shell script run with sudo, or is there a way to run the commands with my user path in the shell script itself?

Here's the script I'd like to have work:

```
#!/bin/bash
#start stuff up

nohup mongod 
#mongod fails as an unknown command, even though it's part of my path

nohup /cust/env/local/cust/jboss-5.1.0.GA/bin/run.sh -b 0.0.0.0 -Djava.awt.headless=true
#jboss needs access to the JAVA_HOME path variable which 
#doesn't exist on the path used in this shell script
```

Comment: Look into `man sudoers`, you can fiddle around with `secure_path`,  `env_reset`, `env_keep`, `env_check`, or possibly even `exempt_group`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this..

```
sudo -i /path/to/script.sh
```

or..

```
sudo env PATH=$PATH /path/to/script.sh
```

or..

```
sudo -E /path/to/script.sh
```

One of them should work, depending on your system.

Comment: When I try to do that, it gives me the error: `-sh: ./script.sh: no such file or directory`. Do you know why that would be?

Comment: @CorayThan- Is your script named `script.sh` and is it chmoded?

Comment: well, really I tried start-mongod-jboss.sh. The real issue would be the chmoded. What does chmoding a script do? The system is a CentOS linux server.

Comment: It makes the script executable.

Comment: specify the full path to the script.

Comment: `sudo -i /the/full/path/to/myscript.sh` is what I got working. I'm not sure why I couldn't reference it as `./myscript.sh` even after I chmoded it.

Comment: I added an answer of my own with all the details I figured out with your inspiration.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that sudos drops the path is a feature. Don't try to work around it by copying the path from the user as some of the examples show. (Imagine if a bad user copies bash into /tmp/ls, then sets PATH=/tmp/. The root shell might do `ls` and accidentally run the bash command with root privileges! Oops, the bad user now has a root shell.)

You could add the extra path by adding this to the top of your script (just under `#!/bin/sh`)

```
. /etc/profile.d/extra-path.sh
```

(The . means "read this file as if it was copied here")

Answer (score 1):

There are a few different solutions to this I've found out.

```
sudo -i [command]
```

and

```
sudo -s [command]
```

both work, but with -i you access the command as if you're in the root directory, so you have to specify the full path to the shell script (or put it in your bin). With -s you access the command as if you're in your current directory.

You can also use these either to run the `myscript.sh` script itself, or use them *inside* the script in front of the commands you need the sudo access for. I preferred to put them in front of those commands as that way I don't have to type out as much to run my script!